# Beautify code in chrome dev tool while using workspace

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way to format/beautify the code in chrome development tool while using workspace feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Chrome Version 40.0.2214.94 (it might be available for older versions). In the bottom part of the editor and upper part of the console, you can find an icon with opening and closing curly brackets. Clicking on the icon will format the code.

[image]